# Appending an array with zeros

Tags: c

I was reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185255/efficiently-appending-a-large-array-with-zeros) and the OP says that he was worried that "*that appending A's allocated memory will corrupt the heap* ", so he instead allocated new memory, memcopy A, and memset.

i was wondering if that is the case. is it not possible to append without allocating new memory.

I made a lame attempt. and i got an error

```
int a[3] = {14, 2, 7};   // initialize array
int M = 2;
int size = sizeof a / sizeof a[0];    // size of array

// print contents of array 
for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
    printf("%d\n", a[i]); 
}

// add (post pad) 2 zeros to existing array , a 
memset(a+M, 0, M * sizeof(int));


int size2 = sizeof a / sizeof a[0];
printf("%d\n", size2);

// print updated array 
for (int i=0;i<size2;i++) {
    printf("%d\n", a[i]); 
}


"*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated"
```

Comment: Arrays sizes are fixed. C doesn't have dynamic arrays. *Also*, C have no bounds checking, it's your job as the programmer to make sure the code doesn't go out of bounds of arrays and allocated memory.

Comment: `int a[3]` means that the `a` array can contain has exactly three elements, period. There is no way to make a C array bigger or smaller.

Comment: It's pointless to speculate about undefined behavior, but in your case you are "corrupting the stack", not the heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C there is no such thing as dynamic arrays. The size of the array must also be constant throughout the program and **cannot** change.

There is also no boundary checking so that is up to you to do as the programmer.

The array you created is a static array with space for 3 integers.

Your call to `memset()` is erroneous.

`memset` requires the following:

```
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);
```

```
s = starting address of memory to be filled

c = value to be filled into memory

n = Number of bytes to be filled starting from s to be filled
```

Your code defines `s` as `a[2]`, this will cause problems because `memset()` will try to access memory beyond what the allocated size of `a` is which can cause a buffer overflow bug.

Secondly it can cause a problem on the stack. Since the array `a` has a set size, when you try to write beyond this set size, you are accessing memory which does not belong to you and potentially over-writing important data in a [stack frame](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/22304/stack-frame#:%7E:text=A%20stack%20frame%20is%20a,existent%20during%20the%20runtime%20process.) that is not yours.

To put it simply the stack contains a unique value known as a "stack canary" which are placed between each stack frame. If this value is overwritten then the operating system knows the next stack frame was overwritten and a stack smashing event occured and an error is shown.

Answer (score 0):

C does not allow you to write to an array out-of-bounds, no matter where it is allocated. Doing so is [*undefined behavior*](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486) and anything can happen.

```
// add (post pad) 2 zeros to existing array , a 
memset(a+M, 0, M * sizeof(int));
```

This code doesn't exactly do what the comment claims, because it starts by overwriting item `a[2]` with zero them continues to write out of bounds 1x`sizeof(int)` bytes from there. What happened in your specific case ("stack smashing") is likely that the code killed a so-called "stack canary" and so the stack corruption was detected. Which is a nice service by the compiler, but by no means guaranteed to happen. You might as well corrupt other variables or cause the program to crash.